Automatically add Maven dependencies when creating a new Java project in VSCode
When I create a new Java project in Visual Studio Code using the ">Java: New Project..." command, my next step is generally to copy and paste in dependencies that I often use, such as Spring, JUnit and Mockito. I don't have their artifactId's memorised, and repeatedly finding the relevant snippet on mvnrepository.com is annoying, and can lead to human error. I could copy them out of a previous project, but I'd still need to double check that the version numbers are up-to-date.
For example, I need JUnit on virtually every project I work on, so I'd like the following added automatically every time I create a new Java project in VSCode:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Is there a way I can configure this snippet to be added automatically? Note the Test scope too.
Using extensions is acceptable here, though I don't know of a way to achieve this using the most common Java and Maven extensions.
An alternative answer could be that when I type something specific to JUnit e.g. @Test, I am prompted with an option to import a JUnit dependency. Again, I'm not aware of anything like this existing (it currently just gives a generic "Test can not be resolved to a type" error).

If you have several projects, or even inside a company, it is worthwhile to write a company parent POM that you can use as parent in different projects.
